# How to Create An Array From User Input

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, scope

```
public class TEST
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string Name = "";
        double Value = 0;
        Array test1 = new Array(Name, Value);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter A Customer:");
            Name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter {0} Insurance Value (numbers only):", Name);
            Value = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        test1.Display();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

So in another class, I have my arrays. The way it is set up, it adds one user at a time to the arrays and adds that users corresponding number in another array.

The part I am having problems with is the main coding. I prompt the user for input and want it to call my other class method and fill the array up one user at a time. BUT, I am stuck.

I know why the code above isn't working, because the object call is only called once and so the initial value is the one that is saved. But when I put the new Array(Name, Value); in the for loop it tells me that test1.Display(); is an unassigned variable.

Is there a way I can solve this. I know there is probably another easier way using list or something, but I haven't gotten that far yet. If you could explain or hint or anything, I'd appreciate it. :)

Comment: What is the `Display` method? That isn't ususally on an array. Your code in general doesn't make much sense really.

Comment: set test1[i] to the Name and declare Name to empty array each time it loops and so on... you are not assingin anything to test1 that is why.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Could you give an example of how / why I would use an array? This was more about practicing manipulating arrays rather than producing useful coding. And, I'd love to know scenario's where I'd actually want to use an array vs list or something else.

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper doesn't that create multiple storage places in memory? I was trying to avoid creating a new array for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is better in this situation to use `List<T>`.

You have to create a class and after that you can create a `List<T>` to save items:

```
public class Customer
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public double Value {get;set;}
}
```

and :

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter A Customer:");
            Customer customer = new Customer(); // create new object
            customer.Name = Console.ReadLine();  // set name Property
            Console.WriteLine("Enter {0} Insurance Value (numbers only):", Name);
            customer.Value = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());// set Value Property
            customers.Add(customer); // add customer to List
        }


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```